# For loop to subtract values between matrices

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have a matrix with 1 column of data in it. The column has `1556480` points of data in it. Call the matrix `Vmatrix`. I have another matrix with `1520` values. Call this `Vmean_matrix`. Is it possible to that a `for` loop can be created to subtract the first value in `Vmean_matrix` from the first `1024` values in `Vmatrix` and the second value in `Vmean_matrix` from the values `1025` - `2048` in matrix `Vmatrix` and so on?

Comment: Show us some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a way:

```
% // Vmatrix = ...
% // Vmean_matrix = ...

len = length(Vmean_matrix);
sub = [];

for ii = 0 : len - 1
    sub = [sub; Vmatrix( ii*1024+1 : (ii+1)*1024 ) - Vmean_matrix(ii+1)];    
end
```

Or to make it faster, you can write it like this way:

```
% // Vmatrix = ...
% // Vmean_matrix = ...

len = length(Vmean_matrix);
sub = zeros(length(Vmatrix), 1);
for ii = 0 : len - 1
    sub( ii*1024+1 : (ii+1)*1024 ) = Vmatrix( ii*1024+1 : (ii+1)*1024 ) - Vmean_matrix(ii+1);    
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Reshape `Vmatrix` into a 1024-row matrix, reshape `Vmean_matrix` into a single row, and subtract with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
result = bsxfun(@minus, reshape(Vmatrix, 1024, []), Vmean_matrix(:).'); %'// 1024 rows
result = result(:); %// linearize if needed
```

Comment: I noticed that `Vmatrix` is `1024 x n` and `Vmean_matrix` is `1024 x 1`. Is it the `bsxfun`'s singleton expansion that kicks in so that   `Vmean_matrix` is expanded to the same size as `Vmatrix`?